# What is the Dr.Watson postmortem debugger?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-error-reporting

Sometimes I get a message **explorer.exe** has stopped working.Then after I click the *Don't send error report* button my icons and taskbar disappears.
Then a Dr.Watson postmortem debugger error appears.
Then nothing happens till I end the process in the task manager.
What is that error appearing for?

Comment: Ahh, Dr. Watson. Brings back memories of good old Windows 3.1. I'm surprised that one is still around, actually.

Comment: It comes in XP too...

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Watson is a Microsoft debugger, i.e., a collector of information useful to technical assistance to diagnose and correct the problem leading to the crash. Unfortunately, Dr. Watson has its own tendency to crash when certain applications crash.

if you want, you may disable Dr.Watson. This of course will not cure your system of the original crash, but it will prevent Dr.Watson itself from crashing. If you are not submitting a crash report, you do not need to have it running.

1.Click Start>Run>type Regedit, then click ok.

2.Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version

3.Select AeDebug in the right panel ,double click on it and enter value 0.

4.Close the Reigistry Editor, reboot.

Alternatively, you may use Microsoft's original instrument to disable Dr.Watson, called FixIt: just click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9749533).